# hosted dotnet core project webapi is not able to connect to database

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Currently I am working in DotNetCore2 web api project from my local machine. It is pointing to remote server database(server : sql6001.site4now.net) . 
I published the same api without making any changes. It seems that deployed api project is also working as I am able to get values from default controller[values] which do not have any database connection required. 
But when i call other methods in controller having database connection required, i am getting nothing. I am not getting any exception, but all I am getting is empty value. 
[

It seems that api project is not able to connect to database , could anybody help in this.

Comment: Advice for asking questions: Could you please take a look at [theses](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) three [articles](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for advice on asking [questions](https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2018/01/25/common-questions-on-stack-overflow-part-one-how-to-get-help/) on Stack Overflow

Comment: With that out of the way, is there a minimal repeatable version of the code which you can share in order for us in the community to help you?